# SettingSyncHost.exe using 50% processor due to denied Registry access

Tags: windows-10, cpu, permissions, windows-registry

I have a Surface Pro 4 which has had the same issue twice now: after logging in `SettingSyncHost.exe` starts using more and more processor until the fans trip and I notice it running at about 50%.

The cause is `SettingSyncHost.exe` writing the same 1K file to `C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\microsoft\InputPersonalization\TrainedDataStore\en-GB\...` over and over again, as fast as it can. Hundreds of thousands of files in that folder by the time I view it.

Further digging found that this is due to the Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InputPersonalization\TrainedDataStore\en-GB\2` being owned by the local admin group, rather than my user account. This means that `SettingSyncHost.exe` is not allowed to access it, and each time it tries the process starts again.

Adding my own account as the owner to those Registry keys fixes the issue, for a while anyway.

This issue has also been seen on [Windows 8.1](https://jader3rd.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/settingsynchost-is-consuming-cpu/) and the [Windows 10 preview](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/9926-settingsynchostexe-causing-25-cpu-load-or-100/1e9dd5ef-9c58-4763-80c5-ae7cae6153a3), but it's still present in Window 10 1607.

What's causing this - why is a reg key only used `SettingSyncHost.exe` owned by a local admin account instead of the user?

How/why does it reoccur?

What is `SettingSyncHost.exe` trying to do and can I disable it?